# Building Financial Data Time Series Database from scratch

Tags: time-series, data, historical-data, database

**My company is starting a new initiative aimed at building a financial database from scratch.**

**We would be using it in these ways:**

1. Time series analysis of: a company's financial data (ex: IBM's total fixed assets over time), aggregations (ex: total fixed assets for the materials sector over time), etc.
2. Single company snapshot: various data points of a single company
3. Analysis of multiple companies across multiple data fields for a single time frame, usually the current day.
4. Backtesting, rank analysis, data analysis, etc. of ideas and custom factors.

**Approximate breadth of data:**

1. 3000 companies
2. 3500 data fields (ex: total fixed assets, earnings, etc.)
3. 500 aggregation levels
4. Periodicity: daily, monthly, quarterly, annual
5. 20 year look-back that would grow over time

**Questions:**

1. **What database should we choose?** We are currently limited to free options and we prefer open source (on principle). Currently we use PostgreSQL.
2. **How should I structure this schema-wise?** I am thinking of breaking up the field types into categories (balance sheet, descriptive, income statement, custom calculations, etc.) so each company would have a table for balance sheet, descriptive, income statement, custom calculations, etc. with each row representing one day and appropriate fields for the category of table for columns/fields. That will be my fully normalized database. Using the fully normalized database, I will then build a data warehouse, temp tables, views, etc. that are not fully normalized to make queries fast for the various use cases described previously. One issue with this approach is the number of tables. If I have, say, 5 categories of company data and 3000 companies I will have 15,000 tables in my fully normalized database for just storing the company data. But still, from my perspective, it seems like the best way to do it.
3. **What is the best strategy for indexing and structuring the time series portion of this?** I've talked to a few people and I did some research on time series database indexing/structure, but help/references/tips/etc. in this area, even if they duplicate what I have found, would be helpful. I realize this depends on the answer to #1 above, so maybe assume I am staying with PostgreSQL and I will be building out the "time series" functionality specific bells and whistles myself.

**Notes:**

- In-depth technical answers and references/links much preferred.
- This is for a small buy side financial investment firm.
- If you have been down this road before, suggestions outside of the scope of my initial question are welcome.
- We cannot compromise on the amount of data, so reducing the amount of data isn't an option for us; however, the numbers I supplied are estimates only.
- If there is a better place to ask this question, please let me know.
- There is much more to what we want to do, but this represents the core of what we want to do from a data structure perspective.

Comment: Have you considered using https://github.com/manahl/arctic ?

Comment: No haven't. Do you think it is a good fit? I skimmed the description and I'm not sure it does better than pg with the column store extension or Cassandra. What do you think?

Comment: I think the API it provides is very friendly and the author says the performance should compare favourably to OpenTSDB / Kairosdb.( I haven' t tested myself.) Kairosdb based on Cassandra might also be worth trying. You can run some benchmarks to see which fits your needs.

Comment: @ mountainclimber, could you please share your feedback on your initiative i.e. which database did you finally choose (did you try other alternatives), pros/cons of current implementation, suggestions etc? Thanks

Comment: @SM4 - Yes, I plan to once we get it into production. I decided to start with a PostgreSQL DB partly because I am familiar with it and I like to support free open sources solutions when I can. So far so good, but we really don't know until we use it a lot. My guess at this early stage is that once we start using it we will see a need to create a data warehouse that will make user queries faster, which was part of the plan. So far, it still seems like we made the correct decision, but time will tell and I plan to update the OQ once I can confidently say how it turned out.

Comment: @ mountainclimber thanks. Actually, I am in a similar spot, but I chose to start w/ flat file schema instead of MS SQL (plan B).  I would love to share with you my experience so far and see how RDMBS performs. What programming environment (C#,C++,Java,Python etc.) are you using to maintain your infrastructure (CRUD operations)? Also, are you getting the data from a third party vendor (Bloomberg, Thomson, Factset)?

Comment: @SM4 - I am coming to the conclusion that many general purpose languages would serve you well for ETL/infastructure/CRUD. I'd say pick something you know and can do the job. Yes third-party data vendor. Happy to collaborate after I am through the thick of it.

Comment: @mountainclimber - how are you dealing with corporate actions? I mean do you store raw (backtesting) and normalized (research) datasets?

Comment: Would it be possible to share your experience and what framework you went for and eventually what framework you are now using (assuming this project is still up-and-running). I am storing my own financial data currently on postgreSQL and I am currently wondering if switching to flatfiles would be more convenient for me ( I found @drobertson answer very interesting/appealing). Interested in your feedback

Comment: @Hotone - after working at a hedge fund since 2011-02-14 and working my way up to CT/CRO, I was fire in 2018 because I wouldn't break Bloomberg's data license agreement. Lol. I left there while I was still developing this project.  So, no info to give in this question. I will likely be revisiting this type of project again with my nonprofit,  Confidence Infinite International. I'll try to post info then. Go luck, don't change anything until you start to bump into issues. Don't future proof too much.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I am going to recommend something that I have no doubt will get people completely up in arms and probably get people to attack me. It happened in the past and I lost many points on StackOverflow as people downvoted my answer. I certainly hope people are more open minded in the quant forum.

Note - It seems that this suggestion has created some strong disagreement again. Before you read this I would like to point out that this suggestion is for a "Small buy side firm" and not a massive multiuser system.

I spent 7 years managing a high-frequency trading operation and our primary focus was building systems just like this. We spent a huge amount of time trying to figure out the most efficient way to store, retrieve and analyze order level data from both the NYSE, NASDAQ and a wide variety of ECNs. What I am giving you is the result of that work.

Our answer was ***Don't Use a Database***. A basic structured file system of serialized data chunks works far better.  Market time series data is unique in many ways, both in how it is used and how it is stored. Databases were developed for wildly different needs and actually hurt the performance of what you are trying to do.

This is in the context of a small to mid-sized trading operation that is focused on data analysis related to trading strategies or risk analytics. If you are creating a solution for a large brokerage, bank or have to meet the needs of a large number of simultaneous clients then I imagine that your solution would differ from mine.

I happen to love databases. I am using MongoDB right now for part of a new project allowing us to analyze options trades, but my market timeseries data, including 16 years of options data, is all built into a structured file store.

Let me explain the reasoning behind this and why it is more performant.

First, let's look at storing the data. Databases are designed to allow a system to do a wide variety of things with data. The basic CRUD functions; Create, Read, Update and Delete. To do these things effectively and safely, many checks and safety mechanisms must be implemented. Before you read data the database needs to be sure the data isn't being modified, it is checking for colisions, etc.. When you do read the data in a database the server puts a lot of effort into caching that data and determining if it can be served up faster later. There are indexing operations and replicating data to prepare it to be viewed in different ways. Database designers have put huge amounts of effort into designing these functions to be fast, but they all take processing time and if they are not used they are just an impediment.

Market time series data is stored in a completely different way. In fact, I would say it is prepared rather than stored. Each data item only needs to be written once and after that never needs to be modified or changed. Data items can be written sequentially, there is no need to insert anything in the middle. It needs no ACID functionality at all. They have little to no references out to any other data. The time series is effectively its own thing.

As a database does all the magic that makes databases wonderful it also packs on the bytes. The minimum space data can take up is its own original size. They may be able to play some tricks with normalizing data and compression, but those only go so far and slow things down. The indexing, caching and referencing the data ends up packing on the bytes and chewing up storage.

Reading is also very simplified. Finding data is as simple as time & symbol. Complex indexing does it no good. Since time series data is typically read in a linear fashion and a sequential chunk at once, Caching strategies actually slow the access down instead of help. It takes the processor cycles to cache the data you aren't going to read again anytime soon.

This is the basic structures that worked for us. We created basic data structures for serializing the data. If your major concern is speed and data size you can go with a simple custom binary storage. In another answer, omencat suggested using [TeaFiles](http://discretelogics.com/teafiles/) and that looks like it has some promise also. Our recent need is for more flexibility so we chose to use a fairly dense, but flexible JSON format.

We broke the data up into fairly obvious chunks. The EOD stock data is a very easy example, but the concept works for our larger datasets also.

We use the data for analysis in fairly traditional time series scenarios. It could be referenced as one quote or out to a series containing years of data at a time. It was important to break the data down to bite-sized chunks for storage so we chose to make one "Block" of our data equal one year of EOD stock time series data. Each block is one file that contains a year of OHLC EOD data serialized as JSON. The name of the file is the Stock symbol prefixed by an underscore. Note - the underscore prevents issues when the stock symbol conflicts with DOS commands such as COM or PRN.

Note, make sure you understand the limitations of your file system. We got in trouble when we put too many files in one place. This led to a directory structure that is effectively its own index. It is broken down by the year of data and then also sorted by the first letter of the stock symbol. This gives us roughly 20 to a few hundred symbol files per directory. It looks roughly like this;

\StockEOD\{YYYY}\{Initial}\_symbol.json

AAPL data for 2015 would be

\StockEOD\2015\A\_AAPL.json

A small piece of its data file looks like this;

```
[{"dt":"2007-01-03T00:00:00","o":86.28,"h":86.58,"l":81.9,"c":83.8,"v":43674760},
{"dt":"2007-01-04T00:00:00","o":84.17,"h":85.95,"l":83.82,"c":85.66,"v":29854074},
{"dt":"2007-01-05T00:00:00","o":85.84,"h":86.2,"l":84.4,"c":85.05,"v":29631186},
{"dt":"2007-01-08T00:00:00","o":85.98,"h":86.53,"l":85.28,"c":85.47,"v":28269652}
```

We have a router object that can give us a list of filenames for any data request in just a handful of lines. Each file is read with an Async filestream and deserialized. Each quote is turned into an Object and added to a sorted list in the system. At that point, we can do a very quick query to trim off the unneeded data. The data is now in memory and can be used in almost any way needed.

If the query size gets too big for the computer to handle it isn't difficult chunking the process. It takes a massive request to get there.

I have had programmers who I described this to almost go into a rage telling me how I was doing it wrong. That this was "Rolling my own database" and a complete waste of time. In fact, we switched from a fairly sophisticated database. When we did our codebase to handle this dropped to a small handful of classes and less than 1/4 of the code we used to manage the database solution. We also got nearly a 100x jump in speed. I can retrieve 7 years of stock end of day data for 20 symbols in a couple of milliseconds.

Our old HF trading system used similar concepts but in a highly optimized Linux environment and operated in the nanosecond range.

Comment: Can't believe you lost points over this! It should be common knowledge (at least in the quant world) that flat files perform and scale better than *any* (even KDB and friends) database.  The only downside is the lack of a query language.

Comment: After quick first read, very interesting! I will research this more. It makes sense conceptually. I'll be back with questions soon. Thanks again!

Comment: @hroptatyr yeah, I think it was some web-oriented guys, but I got slammed for even suggesting flat files could perform better than their beloved database. Even after showing performance data they wouldn't back down. It put me off stack overflow for a while.

Comment: @mountainclimber If you are interested in this approach I would be happy to collaborate. I started one of the earlier high-speed Arb/HFT shops back in 1999 and have been in the business ever since. I am focused on more consumer level projects right now, so no conflict.

Comment: Note - my answer above was focused almost entirely on the time series data. For the fundamentals data, I would strongly suggest a NoSQL solution like MongoDB or some of the fresher database solutions.
A document DB will give you the flexibility you will need for financial data. It is far from standardized and a typical SQL database model will be a challenge to make work in all cases.

Comment: @drobertson - I'm still here, working on this when I can. I would love to collaborate. Is there a way to message users directly in SO?

Comment: No, there is no way to private message in SO. The best bet is to temporarily put up contact information that wouldn't be horrible if it was compromised. Possibly a temporary email address. Then delete it shortly after. If you do put an email up obfuscate it some so it is harder to grab by bots. I am human and can figure out hints. It would be interesting for me to work on this and I am happy to share back with the SO community also.

Comment: @mountainclimber here is a throwaway email address you can use to contact me; tralohidru@throwam.com 
It expires in 48 hours and is useless after that. Just send me your contact info and I will reach out to you using that. This prevents either of us from having to expose a real email on the public site.

Comment: I sent you an email Friday afternoon.

Comment: @mountainclimber yes, I responded to you email in that.

Comment: @hroptatyr to answer an aspect of your earlier comment. We are effectively using LINQ as our query language. It is fairly easy to know what the raw data you need to work with is and LINQ does the heavy lifting for any data wrangling we need. Overall I haven't found many downsides to the aproach.

Comment: If we talk about performance, wouldn't CSV format be more performant? Using less storage and giving you option to load data in chunks vs JSON which you need load whole at once to read it.
You can also easily append data to CSV, while it's not possible with JSON.
Just my thoughts.

Comment: We have done the same but still use 2 databases: we have flat files and use Mongo’s gridfs to store the files. And we send all the data to InfluxDB to have the visualization tools. The data server loads the files and everything needed stays in memory, the queries are hard coded to return result from memory and files get regularly synced with mongodb.

Comment: Regarding the file structures themselves, we went for one file is one column and since everything is time quantized, all space is pre-allocated, including for the foreseeable future so time = index; its big, eats up a lot of ram but it’s insanely fast. The files are just storing binary floats so there is absolutely no overhead.

Comment: So many years passed, don't know if this advice is still valid since there are so many new time series database, like InfluxDB or timeScaleDB etc. But yeah, as NeverEndingQueue pointed out, wouldn't CSV better compared with JSNO

Comment: @user2189731 Technically, Packed Binary would likely be the best choice.

Comment: Thanks. So would you shine some light on why "JSON", if possible? One reason I can think of is the format supporting for date-time? Or maybe you have downstream tool that only support JSON? @drobertson

Comment: Hi @drobertson, very interesting answer! Are you still active here?

Comment: I keep an eye on things but I don't post often.

Comment: @drobertson I am very interested in what you mentioned in your reply and subsequent comments. Since you offered to collaborate on this topic and provided contact details, I wondered if you might be interested in doing it again. I would like to ask you some general questions.

Comment: Hi @drobertson, Would you explain in more details. Why you said that packed binary would likely be the best choice? If the data/database is mapped in memory,   there is no difference between binary or flat file anymore because all the data has been a part of memory.

Answer (score 35):

All of the answers above (unfortunately highly upvoted at this point) are missing the point. You shouldn't pick a DBMS or storage solution by general performance benchmarks, you should pick it by use case. If someone says they get a "x ms read", "y inserts per second", "k times speedup", "store n TB data" or "have m years of experience" and use that to justify a proposal to you, don't trust that person.

I can describe a common breaking point for every single one of the proposed solutions above:

1. Flat files: This is a bad idea when you start to have many client applications, you have a small team, *and/or* you need to access this data in realtime. Even a small team can have hundreds of processes on heterogenous servers hammering the data simultaneously, so you start making this a hardware or file system problem if you store your data in flat files and rely on your own applications to manage concurrent access. Even 10-20 year old RDBMSes do a fairly decent job of managing this that would take nontrivial amount of time for your own developers to replicate. Writing low level concurrent software to deal with network I/O bounds or file system limitations is almost always more expensive than figuring out how to implement a cluster database or sharding with open source tools, and if you have a small team, your developer time is infinitely more valuable than single file query speed. You said that you plan to backtest against the data store - yeah sure, you can backtest at 500 MB/s to 2 GB/s (millions of entries per second, cool!) on a single server with a plain file on a fast SSD, but it's nontrivial to scale this with plain files.
2. Column-oriented time series database: Most people mistake modern database optimizations with the column-oriented advantages. More modern DBMSes have clever parallel radix hash joins, SIMD-based aggregation operations and the likes which explain their speedup. Say, in theory, a row-oriented DBMS should always outperform a column-oriented DBMS in write speed, but you'd see the reverse in many benchmarks because many column-oriented DBMSes have more modern ways to defer metadata generation or maintain indices. In the end, column-oriented is

   i. A bad idea when you almost always *fully materialize* your records *early*. For example, suppose you are just storing {time, best_bid, best_ask} and you are just selecting all the columns in the time interval $[a,b]$ because you are doing exploratory analysis and don't yet know what function $f(best\ bid, best\ ask)$ you want to work with. First, the cache advantage of sequentially going through the times (stored continguously) in $\mathbb{O}(n)$ loses to the algorithmic advantage of chasing pointers through the index B-tree in $\mathbb{O}(\log n)$. Most column-oriented DBMS architects are aware of this and implement their query optimizers to fall back on the index if the query follows this pattern, so both row-oriented and column-oriented DBMS are evenly matched here. But at the materialization step, the column-oriented DBMS still has to deserialize the separate columns back into row-oriented records, whereas the row-oriented DBMS just writes out the data in storage order and should be faster in theory.

   ii. Negligible if your query qualifying sets are usually small. The biggest bottleneck is in loading a disk sector into memory. If your qualifying set is small, all of it lies on the same (few) sector(s) regardless of column-oriented or row-oriented layout, so there is no first order speed advantage in column-oriented layout.

   iii. Expensive if you need third party support. There's only a few production strength column-oriented DBMSes, and getting a contractor to help you here is more expensive than getting free quality assistance on MySQL. If you want realtime applications subscribing to your database, chances are you need an expensive commercial solution because all the open-source options have weak support for such functionality.
3. NoSQL: Let's say you have 2 companies that decide to merge, which happens very often since you are looking at daily granularity. There's different conventions for handling this, but now how do you update the earnings associated with either company? There's no cascade-style data model in MongoDB, so now you offload the work from database-level to application level. This can be bad for a few reasons, (1) chances are, you hand this task to an analyst to do it for you, who is more prone to mess it up than letting the schema ensure integrity for you, (2) you need to write use-case-specific code to update specific fields in your JSON documents, which is difficult to maintain, (3) MongoDB, proposed above, has a rather inefficient serialization format (BSON) and almost all your applications downstream are going to get bottlenecked by the BSON library at some point.

Here's what I suggest you do: **Stick with PostgreSQL because you are already familiar with it, design your schema in a futureproof way that is easy for you to migrate your data to any future solutions, determine where the performance bottlenecks of your use cases are before asking for a more specific solution.**

You'll have to ask your end users what these bottlenecks are. Is it:

1. Backtesting
2. Running time range queries ("Get me all the data columns in this time range.")
3. Running aggregation operations ("I want to find max trade price, calculate total volume etc.")
4. Concurrent access ("I want to write my backtest results on server A while server B is broadcasting the results to server B and C.")
5. Maintaining complex relationships ("I need to know all the dividend date revisions and I have to update them frequently.")
6. Maintaining unstructured relationships ("This asset class has strike prices but this other asset class doesn't.")

The ideal solution differs depending on your use case.

Comment: Thank you very much! Regarding your suggestion to build it then "determine where the performance bottlenecks of your use cases are before asking for a more specific solution" - Is a traditional approach and before asking this question it was my plan. I was however trying to avoid building it twice, if possible. Regarding "design your schema in a futureproof way that is easy for you to migrate your data to any future solutions" - Can you elaborate on what that might look like? What about my 15k table etc. issue mentioned my OQ?   Great stuff, thanks!

Comment: One last question. Can you expand on this statement "it's nontrivial to scale this with plain files"? Can you explain why? Sorry, I don't follow exactly. What aspect makes it not scale well? Thanks!

Comment: @madilyn I am sorry that you felt the need to attack my answer. It is based on years of doing what I perceive to be his need. It was also specifically addressing the Time Series data which I have been actively working with for 17 years. I will make the assumption that you haven't worked with flat file data much because a few of your points are wrong. File systems are extremely easy to program against these days and I have not seen any issues relating to the FS since the mid-90s.

Comment: @madilyn  I also have done the same work above in MS SQL. The file system based code is easier to maintain and much faster for my needs. LINQ in .NET gives me an extremely flexible query system and adding a caching layer is easy to do if my use case has the need for repeated requests for the same data.

Comment: @mountainclimber The performance doesn't suffer at all as you add new data. The entire indexing of the time series data is built into the naming of the files and folders. Since this is not relational data the indexing does not get more complex as you add data. The performance is a roughly linear relationship to the amount of data you request.

Comment: @madilyn I am a bit frustrated with the tone of your answer. If you would like to discuss the merits of each approach I would be happy to do that, but it doesn't benefit anyone to lash out at other answers.

Comment: This opinionated and IMO biased answer nevertheless, ironically, comes to a fairly good conclusion: "just use postgres". However it is misguided to dismiss column stores with a long, jargon-laden but seemingly confused point 2.i) where it is clear that if you have a range-query use case a column store will outperform a non column store, and the idea that algos will default to a tree search as opposed to a hash function is stupid and reflects serious bias. 

What you need to understand is that column store use case sits IN BETWEEN a flat file system and a full RDBMs. They exist for a reason.

Comment: Point 2.ii) is absolutely correct, but in finance, we are often going to need large range queries, and my sense is that preparing for that eventuality, even if you don't use it up front, is wise.  

Point 2.iii) however is utter nonsense. There are vibrant forums for both Cassandra and Hbase, bot are completely open source, the former is very easy to setup and trivially easy to scale, most definitely an order of magnitude easier to manage than Postgres at anything that even starts to resemble scale.

Comment: "What you need to understand is that column store use case sits IN BETWEEN a flat file system and a full RDBMs." -> I generally agree with what you've written but this is founded on a naive understanding of column-oriented vs row-oriented. There is nothing that precludes a column-oriented database from having a relational data model, and therefore there is no 'inbetween'. In fact the most respectable column stores have a relational paradigm (Vertica, Vectorwise, Monet).

Comment: "There are vibrant forums for both Cassandra and Hbase." -> You are missing my point. Every DBMS named in this thread has a forum, open source community, and supporting documentation, however there's almost certainly fewer companies that provide enterprise support for Cassandra and Hbase. This is an important consideration for a small buy-side company that sometimes needs to outsource parts of its infrastructure development in a paid contract (in exchange for confidentiality). You can't get a forum to sign a NDA and help you design your database.

Comment: "However it is misguided to dismiss column stores with a long, jargon-laden but seemingly confused point" -> Again, you don't seem to have read my point properly. In fact I'm largely in favor of column stores for most use cases, I'm pointing out that (i) without knowing the exact use case, you can find a weakness in every solution proposed here, and (ii) as such, general benchmarks are pointless without knowing the use case.

Comment: This last point is essentially "horses for courses" and is unfortunately highly prevalent on all the stack exchanges and answers precisely nothing. One has to try to infer from where this fellow is coming from, and since there are 3500x3000 series one can reasonably postulate that we're talking about quite a lot of data, hence the column stores come into play. I think in general you are flying at far too high a level in your buzzword/jargon density to be useful to the OP. Flat files are, as you correctly point out, probably a bad choice. But relational v noSQL is a much more subtle discussion.

Comment: "...in between flat file and full RDBMS"... your equivalency argument. No. They're not the same. Because they're optimised for different use cases, and NoSQL does not burden itself with normalization and relational integrity. They were built, in the 2000s, precisely because RDBMSs were suboptimal for large amounts of generally flattish data. Of course they're also able to behave relationally, but usually client side, which is an utterly crucial difference which *must* be understood for correct advice, as it has all sorts of implications.

Comment: IMO, if I were to summarize all of this, I would say a) flat files bad, b) postgres good *unless* c) you have lots of range queries along one dimension and/or you have truly big data. 

You should not listen to anyone who says that RDBMS == NoSQL capabilities because that is simply not true. If that were true, noSQL would not exist today.

Comment: Here's some reading that will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798251/whats-the-difference-been-nosql-and-a-column-oriented-database

Comment: This is a strawperson. I said that you can have a relational column-oriented store, you parsed this as me saying that you can have relational NoSQL. It is clear you're coming at this from angle where you've only seen Cassandra and think that column-oriented implies NoSQL just because Cassandra is column-oriented and 'column-optional'.

Comment: Lastly, I'm sorry if the content comes across as dense "jargon". I'm actually tuning down to language you would use in a first course in modern databases. Generally anyone who has had 1 research paper exposure to modern (post-2007) database research would be familiar to all these via a Stonebraker or Kersten school paper. It's really meaningless to contrast performance between modern DBMSes if you don't at least talk about materializations, B-trees, cache and query optimization.

Answer (score 16):

Interesting debate and `Not to wake sleeping dogs`, the world has moved quite a bit in the 1.5 years, and the data space has exploded.

I would like to recommend some new technologies and at the same time share a few of my experiences in this space.

As @madilyn is trying to explain: It all depends on your use case. In my experience it's easy to know what you want to do today, but really hard to foresee all the future use cases. Therefore I also take the agility into account when making a choice of the stack to use for a given system.

Flat files is just really powerful especially if they are stored in a binary format (e.g. [tea](http://discretelogics.com/teafiles/), [HDF5](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/), [Feather](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/03/29/feather/), [Apache Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/)), using JSON and serializing / de-serializing the data is not clever at all.

When dealing with huge amounts of rows of structured data a modern Column-oriented database is hard to beat, especially in combination with interesting technologies like snappy (compression that... well compress AND gives faster i/o - What!?!) and distributed file systems (e.g. GlusterFS, GridFS, CEPH), that allows you to build a relative inexpensive and scalable database cluster, check out [MariaDB Columnstore](https://mariadb.com/products/technology/columnstore) and the super performant (but with some drawbacks) [Clickhouse](https://clickhouse.yandex/).

Most of the data in finance is having the time dimension, so it might be a good idea of thinking this into the?
[KDB+](https://kx.com/discover/) has been around for decades with a super strong database, unfortunately mostly unavailable for smaller companies due to cost. Now a whole sub-industry is emerging, fueled by the IoT buzz, offering time series databases (e.g. [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/), [RiakTS](http://basho.com/products/riak-ts/), [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net/)), but in my opinion the latest and still relative unknown contender [TimescaleDB](https://www.timescale.com/) offers some truly unique features.
TimescaleDB is an extension to PostgreSQL and offers time series capabilities inside the same database of where your non-time-dimensional data resides, making it easy to JOIN together and in general leveraging PostgreSQL's large feature set.

The query language is really important, and in my opinion nothing beats SQL (and NewSQL) in terms of compatibility. By forcing other people to learn and use CQL or MongoDB Query Language, you might very well end up building a data graveyard.

When NoSQL was at the peak of its hype, I was one of the cool kids onboard with a MongoDB database, quickly I realized that a. I was the only user b. I wanted to use BI tools for the early data exploration, MongoDB have properly had a lot of customers with the same request, so luckily they have made a 'Connector for BI'. I tried both the official one and a bunch of the SQL connectors made by 3rd party vendors, and let me just say this: You don't have to do the same experiment, unless you wish to waste a day or two of your life.

---

Conclusion
I will (partly) side with @madilyn **PostgreSQL with TimescaleDB extension** might be the way to go for the OP, but if you’re not already married to PostgreSQL then also checkout **MariaDB Columnstore**, once you have a nice solution, then **build a feature/script to extract data into a binary file** for one-off / event research.

Comment: Good answer, agreed that the different DBMSes and serialization formats suggested are all possible candidates. Also I need to add that a common problem with all the modern candidates available to us is that very few of them have well-maintained hooks to cluster middleware or anything you're doing to orchestrate distributed computing, which means you may actually get better productivity by sacrificing performance for a more commonly used solution which has a wider software community. Many of top firms are still using HDFS even if it's notoriously slow.

Comment: Postgre also has a column store extension https://github.com/citusdata/cstore_fdw

Answer (score 15):

The standard answer is going to be that for time series, you want a column store database. These are optimized for range queries (ie: give me everything between two timestamps) because crucially, they store data along one of the dimensions (which you must choose, usually time) contiguously on disk, and thus reads are extremely fast. The alternative, when fully normalizing on a relational database, is that time will be indexed, but not stored contiguously. Thus if you ask for, say 3000 data points, you're hitting the index 3000 times, and even if said index is held entirely in memory (unlikely if you have 3000 companies x3500 fields), this takes a lot of time. Anecdotally, even using MongoDB, which is very vast, I obtained a 100x speed up using Cassandra. Hbase will equally serve you well, while lesser known entrants such as RiakTS, InfluxDB et al, are more specialized towards time series, and often don't have tool support (for example, Flink or Spark). I have found Cassandra to suit my needs very well, but then, I don't have as many fields as you (though it will handle them with ease). However I do store vast amounts of timeseries data (intraday) and Cassandra also has very high ingest rates.

*However*. You mention normalization. Cassandra et al will not give you normalization. They will not give you anything like the sophisticated integrity tools which relational databases provide, nor the complex schema options. In particular, if you want column-store speed along more than one of the axes in your data hybercube, you will need to repeat the data transposed form. Otherwise it will revert to relational performance (ie: you can still index across dimensions, of course). If you find that most of your queries will be along the time axis, and that you don't have much need for complex schemas, I would heartily recommend Cassandra. It is heavily used in the financial industry for this reason.

An option which might be equivalent for you however, is Postgres with its column store capabilities. You can specify to Postgres that it should store data along one axis contiguously, thereby getting the benefit of the column stores. Note however that Postgres doesn't scale across multiple machines nearly as easily as Cassandra or Hbase. You'll have to scale it vertically, which is much much more expensive when you start pushing the envelop on ingest or query performance. With Cassandra, you just add cheap boxes. We all know that 10 cheap boxes are much cheaper than the single monster box that will keep up with their (parallelized) performance. Indeed at some performance levels, relational will just choke, whereas Cassandra will scale linearly to as many boxes as you like (Apple reportedly runs 75000 nodes). That's why Netflix uses Cassandra, as does Apple. You'll need some serious z-enterprise style big iron if you want to try to get close to the performance of even a medium sized Cassandra cluster, with a relational database.

So, Postgres or Cassandra. It will probably come down to whether or not you are going to put the data up for public (ie large number of users) consumption, or if your data is truly big (> 5 terabytes ish is what I call "big"). In that case Cassandra. Or if you need computer-science rigorous normalization and all the bells and whistles that Postgres will give you, and indeed it is an excellent choice (with column store) if you are not too worried about truly big data growth.

Comment: Thomas Browne - I am researching your very in-depth answer. Thank you! Is this the pg columnar store feature/extension you were referring to: https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2014/04/03/columnar-store-for-analytics/

Answer (score 5):

Regarding storage, I stream real-time updates for exchange listed contracts (outright + exchange listed calendar spreads) to [InfluxDB](https://influxdata.com/). Its a time-series database, mostly geared towards IT Ops for storing log data, but it works fine with homogeneous finance data.

For options strips, due to the sheer amount of data generated per day, I use [TeaFiles](http://discretelogics.com/teafiles/). Pros for using teafiles are that the file sizes are small, and load times are fast. For each .tea file I assign the following strategy: `[ContractSymbol]_[Strike]_[CallOrPut]_[Date].tea`. Files are then stored in Azure BLOB storage. Read benchmarks are good; ~25ms to read a file with 300k entries from a C# loader.

Comment: I considered using InfluxDB at one point, but the server spec requirements scared me off. I would be curious to hear your experience with that system in production.

Comment: I posted the answer using JSON data above. I had not seen TeaFiles before this. They seem to perform the same function as my JSON data. I am interested in seeing how the two perform side by side. Thanks for pointing me in this direction and I gave you an upvote for that.

Comment: Sure thing, tea files do not serve the same function as JSON. tea files are binary files with headers designed for homogeneous time series. Where as JSON is designed for attribute=value objects in human readable text files. If you are not capturing high-frequency intraday updates, then tea files may not be the best solution for you. But if you find yourself having to load millions/tens of millions of time-series for each query, then a binary based storage solution should at least be considered. Here are some [performance metrics](http://discretelogics.com/resources/benchmarks/teafilesbm.htm/)

Comment: Thanks for the stats. I think I may run a test or two with my own data and see what json vs TeaFiles looks like side by side. It doesn't look like the conversion would be hard and you have me curious. JSON gives me some flexibility for adding data and deserializing into multiple objects types, but there is a bit of a performance hit for that. TeaFiles may give me a bit of a boost where I don't need flexibility. I have about 10 years of Options quotes that would be a good test. If I get some results I will post them back.

Answer (score 2):

I will prefix my answer with the following:

- I've not read the holy wars stuff in the other answers in detail. I think it's missing the point.
- I've implemented exactly this project more than once in small buy side firms.

Your main issue is getting the data in the first place. I have a recommendation - S&P Capital IQ. You can get a deployment where you either:

- connect to their database server in the cloud
- deploy their loaders and database on your hardware (there's a choice of target OS and database, so if your org is Postgres / SQL server / Oracle, its not an issue - just pick what your guys prefer).

The loaders take care of sync'ing the data, and the schema.

I've used similar competing products from other vendors and S&P was the only one that had what I would call a 'sane' data structure. SQL queries are pretty straightforward, and your average quant analyst will have no issue at all getting what they want. The documentation is good, and they have support teams that actually have a clue.

If you want to extract that data into something that suits your analytic workload better, then it's much easier to do that from a properly organised dataset. I'm specifically talking about extract to another storage for faster processing. For most quant workloads its going to be either:

- snapshot the DB to my temp copy
- read into Python etc, do work, dump snapshot to my local disk
- some other file format / database for highly concurrent analytic workload (Tableau, Apache Spark, custom calc, etc)

The only issue with S&P is cost - but you were going to need to buy something anyway, as collecting it yourself is totally infeasible. They are far cheaper than Bloomberg, and I cannot recommend Thomson Reuters.

Don't worry too much about scalable tech storage etc, the real issues are cleaning the data, identifiers and dealing with things like corporate actions. That's waaaaay harder.

Regarding the tech:

Postgres is fine, and it won't annoy with issues like float precision etc. There is now TimescaleDB that gives you some pretty powerful time series performance for zero $, without forcing you to silo the time series data from the reference data.

For the kind of data you are talking about, you won't need a clustered database solution if your data is reasonably normalised. S&P's product is, and for that dataset size, it was a couple of TB iirc.

Comment: How is Capital IQ from a date reliable standpoint? Also, what frequency of data do they have? Do they have tick?

Comment: I am going to assume that you mean 'data' rather than 'date': Capital IQ actually offer bad data bounty, while other vendors have told me that I was wrong even when presented with evidence. That says it all really. However, if you have niche requirements then you should look for yourself as some vendors do better than others in niche areas. I don't know if they have tick data. The deepest tick history set I know of is Reuters, starting from 1996. If you need 5-10 years, then there are many options out there.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is QAdirect.  The data is from various sources, and you can add in your own custom tables.  The schema is well documented, and extraction is via the usual SQL technologies.  As far as cost goes, it costs, but not as much as Bloomberg.

They seem to be committed to getting information from new sources, which will help in this heterogeneous environment.

I know of several shops that combined QAdirect, Capital IQ/alpha-factor library, Datastream, along with Facset and Bloomberg for point solutions.

The real problems with all of this cost.  I have seen suppliers start to ramp up prices and are trying to build strangleholds on the data sources.  The control of the data is the real battle for the right to charge rent from investors these days.

Answer (score 0):

DolphinDB is designed for your use-case. It is really powerful and performant though it is not open-sourced and requires a commercial license.

Answer (score 0):

[Axibase Time Series Database](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/finance/) FINANCE Edition is built exactly for storing and retrieving Last sale, Level 1, and reference data.

It's faster than files and comes with custom SQL functions for fast filtering and aggregation.

```
SELECT datetime, symbol, open(), close(), vwap()
    FROM atsd_trade
  WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2021-01-01' EXCL
    AND IS_INSTRUMENT_IN_INDEX('<index_name>')
    -- AND exchange = 'LSE' AND class = 'IOB' AND symbol = 'RDS.A'
  GROUP BY exchange, class, symbol, period(1 HOUR)
```

Notice functions such as `vwap()` which are not part of standard SQL, or
`IS_INSTRUMENT_IN_INDEX` function which filters trades by components that belonged to the index on the trade date (not only current components).

More SQL examples are listed [here](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/finance/sql.html). Also, how to handle [option EOD](/questions/60850/storing-options-eod-time-series-in-flat-files/61100#61100) data.

The database is free for production on a single node.

(Disclaimer: I work for Axibase)

Answer (score 0):

[QuestDB](https://questdb.io/) is also another option. Billed as "the fastest open source time series database".