# Using Timeseries DB for Tracking Asset Performance over time

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, asset-returns

I am building a system that allows users to purchase digital assets, and i would like to know the  asset's performance of individual users.

A user may purchase an asset multiple time in a single day, at difference 'offer' price and likewise, a user may also sell their asset in a single day, at different 'bid' price.

Currently i store information such as accounts and transaction in postgresql, however i need to regularly store the %-age gain/loss and amount gain/loss of individual users at different timestamp so that i can analyze the performance over time.

For example, i can compare a user's performance today vs last thursday. Or This quarter vs last quarter, or Q1 this year vs Q1 last year.

My main concern is on how i should store the data, i am thinking of using timeseries database such as influx or prometheus.

I am still in the research stage as to what database should i use, and i am really open for suggestion.

Comment: Have a look at Timescale DB (https://www.timescale.com/). It is built on postgres so you can do anything you could do before, but it has timeseries operations made native as well. Open source (free) version available.

Comment: Have a read through this post from a few years ago.  Lot's of options and opinions!  https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29572/building-financial-data-time-series-database-from-scratch/29679#29679